# What is the URL for NuGet Gallery to access (nuget.org) from VS2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, nuget

What is the URL for NuGet Gallery to access (nuget.org) from VS2010 
via Package Manager Console? I tried to use the Web site URL 
(http://nuget.org/List/Packages) but it didn't work.

Comment: Looking at all the answers below, makes me think nuget has a problem. All of these answers points to an architecture smell.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=206669

That maps to: http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/ but you should use the Go link to future-proof yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I just discover it :)

Comment: The URL above is an old one, see my answer below for the newer URL to the version 2 NuGet feed.

Comment: Current link is https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json hidden at the bottom of their [FAQ page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/resources/nuget-faq).

Answer (score 184):

With NuGet 3, the url has changed again, it's now `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`.

Microsoft Docs should always list the latest feed address:
[Use packages from nuget.org > Enable the upstream on an existing feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops#enable-the-upstream-on-an-existing-feed).

Comment: Why oh why is this so difficult to find on NuGet.org? It should be featured prominently on the landing page. I need to find this answer every time - thanks!

Comment: For even better copypaste:
<add key="nugetorg" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />

Comment: In my case, it kept getting blocked by the company's firewall,have to ask and reask whenever it got blocked... The security guy blame the URL, what the f is wrong with nuget anyway. Every other site I use pass the firewall

Comment: I know it's late, but this bit me.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/nuget-org/overview-nuget-org#api-endpoint-for-nugetorg is a direct link to MS documentation for the current NuGet API endpoint.  Looks like v3 is still current.

Answer (score 32):

The Microsoft Go link in the accepted answer above is an old one, the correct URL is: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=230477

This points to https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/, which is the NuGet version 2 package source feed.

I tend to use the actual URL, not the Go link anyway. As proven by the two different Go links, there is no guarantee it won't change as well, so I find it more explicit to point to the actual URL.

The Microsoft Go links are, in my opinion, a bad idea. They completely obscure the actual web URL, which defeats the purpose of HTTP addresses in the first place.

Comment: Note that there is a new feed URL as of [NuGet 3.0](http://blog.nuget.org/20151008/NuGet-3-What-and-Why.html): `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`

Answer (score 14):

The **most up to date nuget package url** should be documented here:

**[Microsoft Nuget FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/resources/nuget-faq#i-don-t-see-nuget-org-in-my-list-of-repositories--how-do-i-get-it-back-)**

(as at this moment, that would be: **https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json**)

For the life of me, I do not understand why this is not displayed prominently on nuget.org landing page. ‍♂️

Comment: Now I think the better place for Nuget to maintain this URL is **[Overview of NuGet.org -> API endpoint for Nuget.org](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/nuget-org/overview-nuget-org#api-endpoint-for-nugetorg)**.

Answer (score 2):

I found that http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=206669 points to the full NuGet Gallery while the default registered url https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=206669 (watch the protocol: Https) points only to the Official NuGet package source.

Answer (score -2):

For reference, you can check what the supported URLs are by going directly to the NuGet site here: https://www.nuget.org and looking under the heading 'NuGet Feed Locations'

Comment: one year later - and no such heading. Really, this info _should_ always stay on their landing page!

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  The URL is not on the homepage.

Comment: Microsoft's go links have always been worthless. They change everything every couple of years. The concept of a permalink is unknown to them. So much frustration!