# Simple.Odata.Client resource not found

Tags: c#, odata

I am following a tutorial from [Github](https://github.com/simple-odata-client/Simple.OData.Client/wiki/Getting-started-with-Simple.OData.Client) that seems to error when I call the 'await client' line below. The error is `Simple.OData.Client.WebRequestException: 'Resource Not Found'` however the url works fine when I visit it in a browser. Any idea how to troubleshoot this further?

Main.cs:

```
using Simple.OData.Client; //Install-Package Simple.OData.Client

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MCdemo().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static async Task<string> MCdemo()  
{
    var client = new ODataClient("https://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/");

    var x = ODataDynamic.Expression;
    IEnumerable<dynamic> packages = await client
        .For(x.Packages)
        .Filter(x.Title == "Simple.OData.Client")
        .FindEntriesAsync();

    foreach (var package in packages)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(package.Title);
    }

    return "success";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that exception because that is an old URL to Nuget packages.The tutorial should have been updated. The new Nuget url is https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json, see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693139/what-is-the-url-for-nuget-gallery-to-access-nuget-org-from-vs2010) and [Github](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2237)

But for your tutorial you can use this http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/

```
var client = new ODataClient("http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/");

var x = ODataDynamic.Expression;
IEnumerable<dynamic> values = await client
    .For(x.Photos)
    .FindEntriesAsync();

    foreach (var photo in values)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(photo.Name);
    }

return "success";
```