# Error Occured when trying to install NuGet Packages

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I am trying to install a NuGet package but the following from the pictures happens:[The error occured message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cupj4.png)
[This is my NuGet packages source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJypa.png)

Could the source be wrong or something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the URL for NuGet Gallery to access (nuget.org) from VS2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693139/what-is-the-url-for-nuget-gallery-to-access-nuget-org-from-vs2010)

Comment: I retagged this to [visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-studio/info), not [visual-studio-code](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-studio-code/info) because this looks like it's for Visual Studio. They are not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is not able to find the package or file at the address. This is indicated by the "404 Not Found" message in the 'Output' window. I notice you have the source set to "MyNuGet". On my NuGet manager mine is set to "nuget.org". This may be why it isn't able to find the packages.

Although I did see in your other image it says that 'MyNuGet' is referencing "https://api.nuget.org". My NuGet manager references "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" try changing it to this URL instead.